# Windows Phone 8: checkbox doesn't fit

Tags: windows-phone-8, wpf-controls

I am getting started on my first WP8 project and ran in to an issue. The control I am designing has a height of 48px, but the Checkbox control seems to have a padding that prevents it from displaying correctly on a space smaller than 75px. Is that correct? If not, how can I get the checkbox to shrink down and display correctly?

[image]

It's hard to tell from the pic, but the margins and padding are all set to 0.

Comment: Try adding `Height="Auto"` to your `CheckBox` or set it to a fixed value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Checkbox` default template is made up of a grid of two columns. The default margins of this grid is set to `PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang` which is defined as 12, 20, 12, 20.

The easiest way to modify any control is through blend. You can do the following to remove the margins and do any other modifications you want:

1. Right-click on your user control file in VS and and choose 'Open in Blend...'
2. In Blend, select your check box then right-click and choose Edit Template-->Edit Copy. Accept defaults and click ok.
3. Leave Blend and make sure to save.

You will see a bunch of style definitions were created for you in the xaml file. In Checkbox case, 3 were created.

To remove the margin locate the style named `CheckBoxStyle1` and scroll to the end of this definition where you'll see a line like this:

```xml
<Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
```

Change it to

```xml
<Grid Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
```

Margins should be gone. Note that according to design guidelines touchable controls should have a minimum 12 pixel spacing between them so make sure to modify your control to provide that.